# query with search terms in specific elements in opensearch?

Tags: atom-feed, opensearch, atompub, apache-abdera

Just starting with Opensearch, to retrieve content from the Nationaal Archief from the Netherlands.

The example they provide is:

```
http://www.gahetna.nl/beeldbank-api/opensearch/?q=Arnhem
```

My question is, how to search for "Arnhem" in specific elements? For example, I'd like to get only the documents that have "Arnhem" in their "dc:subject" element:

```
<dc:subject>Arnhem, a Dutch city</dc:subject>
```

And since I use **Abdera** as a Java client, any pointer as to which helper method would assist in building  such a query would also be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The OpenSearch standard does not define any way to specify metadata or context of a query, as far as I can see in www.opensearch.org.
Maybe your archive supports other interfaces?